# Can I use the Google Weather API in a commercial project?

Tags: api, google-api, weather, weather-api, google-weather-api

Can I use the Google Weather API in a commercial project, if I just added a "weather powered by Google" link?

Comment: **The Google weather API was shut down in 2012.** See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145820/google-weather-api-gone/35943521

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the Google Weather API is not even an officially supported API, but a 'hack' found and documented by [other people](http://blog.emerick.org/2008/05/07/google-weather-api-feed-documentation/). So there is no terms of use that defines if you can use it commercially.

But if you look at a similar [API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) offered by Yahoo, its terms of use explicitly prohibit commercial use, so I wouldn't gamble on using Google's API in your project.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know the Google weather API is not an officially supported public Google API. It's internally used e.g. by Google Calendar or iGoogle. Therefore I think, the legal status is somehow indefinite.