# Google Weather API gone?

Tags: ios, xcode, weather, weather-api, google-weather-api

I had been using the following google weather api in my iPhone apps to get 4 day weather forecast.

```
NSString *address = @"http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Chicago";
    NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",address];

    NSLog(@"request: %@", request);

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:request];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *XML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

    NSLog(@"XML: %@", XML);
    NSLog(@"XML lenght: %d", [XML length]);
```

As of yesterday Aug 25th, 2012 I get absolutely nothing back! I don't get any results back. When did this happen? Did Has anyone else experience this same problem?

This is a really critical issue as I have multiple weather / clock apps that look for google weather api and they all are crashing as I expect some results back in my XML string!

Comment: I truly hope the rumors are not true but looks like I am not the only one experiencing the same problem. Google has stopped its weather api support.  Now not only I ave to find another api but update all my 15 apps not to mention 15 day approcal process with apple. What a pooper! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139862/android-cant-get-weather-from-google-api

Comment: Well, I'm sorry this happened to you but maybe you should take care not to use private APIs in production products in the future. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Weather API seems to be "officially" dead, which is ironic to say, because it was never officially a supported API to begin with. There has been no official announcement from Google, but it should be noted that iGoogle is now using Wunderground's API for weather data.

http://igoogle.wunderground.com/US/CA/Mountain_View.html

So no, you're not seeing things. The Google Weather API is gone. I experienced the same thing. It's time to move on and find a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in getting XML that looked and felt like google weather api then use this [MSN weather API list of conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142094/msn-weather-api-list-of-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Google stopped their weather API, i found another one from the website [yr.no](http://yr.no) and i use it in my website [weathercase.net](http://www.weathercase.net) via PHP which is wonderful

Answer (score 0):

**The Google weather API was shut down in 2012.**

If you're looking for an alternative to the google weather API, these are the three most popular weather APIs at the moment :

- [**Yahoo! Weather**](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)
- [**Wunderground**](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api)
- [**OpenWeatherMap**](http://openweathermap.org/api)

Check their respective documentation pages for more info on how to use them!

Answer (score 0):

From this time Weather Underground API and Dark Sky API were shut down too. Although [Dark Sky API is still working until 2021](https://blog.darksky.net/), we have to look for a replacement. I hope that OpenWeather with their new [One Call API](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api) will help anyone who needs powerful weather API at this moment.