# Google Weather API is not working, sending strange response

Tags: android, google-weather-api

I was using the Google Weather API from quite sometimes but from Yesterday, I am getting strange message `"Unsupported API"`.
I have searched on Google but didn't find any official declaration for same.
Does any one experiencing same problem or its problem with me alone.

Comment: **The Google weather API was shut down in 2012** -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145820/google-weather-api-gone/35943521

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google plans to completely shut down iGoogle, and as it prepares to do that it is shutting down the weather API which was used by iGoogle.

In fact, iGoogle has shifted to using wunderground.com's api till the service is completely retired in 2013.

You can see from [this status board](http://status-dashboard.com/32226/47728) that the API had stopped responding to requests from the 27th.

Comment: ok thanks man now its clear have to find another api for this do you know any?.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but you could try wunderground.com - it is what Google decided to replace their own weather API with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes wunderground.com is a good site for the weather apis. You can use one of the API given by the wunderground.com is http://api.wunderground.com/api/431c96428597b3ce/conditions/autocomplete/forecast/q/India/Bangalore.json

Comment: the api you mentioned above.. is this available for commercial use??